# How to give alias to results returned after inner join in mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to do a correlated SQL Query and for that purpose i need to provide an alias to outer query which in which I perform an inner join. I am not able to do the alias

```
    SELECT DISTINCT(name) 
     FROM PERSON
     INNER JOIN M_DIRECTOR AS dira
     ON (dira.PID = M_DIRECTOR.PID) as dira
     WHERE 9 > (
         SELECT COUNT(MID) FROM M_DIRECTOR WHERE name = dira.name
    ) ;
```

Comment: what you mean ? what column you want give alias ?

Comment: Why are adding alias for the `on` condition

Comment: @echo_Me is it not possible to alias an entire result? say here the te tuples returned by outer query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't really understand what you want to do, but I guess

```
select 
    distinct p.name,
    count(d.MID) cnt
from 
    hindi2_PERSON p
inner join 
    hindi2_M_DIRECTOR d
on 
    p.PID = d.PID
group by
    p.name
having count(d.MID) > 9
;
```

would do what you want

Comment: Try the query, this should exactly do what you describe!

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what you are asking and what you mean by make an alias to an eniter result ?

but you are doing

```
   select distinct(name) as othername
```

which is you are selecting `name` and you are giving here `othername` as an alias

then you retrieve it in result

```
   $row['othername']
```

Answer (score -2):

There's still something missing. From what you write, there is a field name in the M_DIRECTOR table?
Please show all the tables and attributes involved, use an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/about.html) to prepare an example.

```
    SELECT DISTINCT(name) 
    FROM PERSON as p
    INNER JOIN (
            SELECT COUNT(MID), PID FROM M_DIRECTOR WHERE name = dira.name 
    ) as d
    ON (p.PID = d.PID) ;
```